# How to mount a Mac OS X 10.10 shared volume with Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: linux, mount, mac, autofs

I'm attempting to mount a Mac OS X 10.10 shared volume via Ubuntu Server 14.04.1. I've set this up successfully between two Macs but I'm having a problem Ubuntu to Mac.

I've setup the shared volume "myStorage" via the Mac's Sharing System Preference panel.
I've setup autofs file on the Ubuntu box as follows.

I've created a mount point:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/server
```

**File: /etc/auto.master**

```
/mnt/server     /etc/auto.server        --timeout=6000  --ghost
+auto.master
```

**File: /etc/auto.server**

```
mymountpoint -fstype=cifs,credentials=/root/autofs.creds ://ip_address_here/myStorage -o iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp,rw,nounix
```

**File: /root/autofs.creds**

```
username=MYDOMAIN\myusername
password=mypassword
```

I'm receiving these errors when trying to navigate to the mount point /mnt/server/myStorage. The mount point does show in the /mnt/server directory, but the result is:

```
-bash: cd: myStorage/: No such file or directory
```

in /var/log/syslog:

```
Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

I've installed *cifs-utils*
Any ideas on what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you mount it the long way to test/compare? `mount.cifs //server/sare /mnt/server -o user=myusername,password=mypassword,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,noperm,rw`

Comment: trying this, get error: mount.cifs: permission denied: no match for /mnt/server found in /etc/fstab. Do I need to add something to fstab?

Comment: You only need to add stuff to `/etc/fstab` if you want it to start up during boot.  Since we'e just testing to see if you can mount at all, it's not important.  Can you verify `/mnt/server` exists?

Comment: yes. /mnt/server does exist

Comment: Try mounting with sudo: `sudo mount.cifs //server/sare /mnt/server -o user=myusername,password=mypassword,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,noperm,rw`

Comment: Tried with sudo and received error =>   mount error(13): Permission denied

Comment: Permission denied means it didn't like the username/password format.  Are you including your domain in the username?

Comment: Tried with domain and received the same error  mount error(13): Permission denied

Comment: Try putting this into your `/etc/fstab`: `//server/share /mnt/server cifs sec=ntlmv2,credentials=/root/autofs.creds,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0` and then run `mount -a` to see if it mounts